# Passing EC2 parameter store variables to an ECS task as environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Is there any to pass parameters from EC2 parameter store as environment variables to an ECS task?

AWS provides us with
1) A way to store parameters, both secret and less secret
2) A way to set environment variables inside ECS tasks
but no way to connect the to - or am I missing something?

[Here](https://www.whaletech.co/2017/08/01/Secure-Credentials-for-ECS-Tasks.html) a solution is described where you wrap the docker image in your own image *only* to be able to load parameters. If this is the recommended way then I will have to wrap all images from Docker Hub that I could otherwise use as stock images and do nothing beside configure them via environment variables.

I feel like this forces me to take on an unnecessary amount of responsibility for coding, maintaining, storing, etc. of docker images where I would otherwise only have to set environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was recently posted by AWS on how to access Parameter store in an ECS task. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/managing-secrets-for-amazon-ecs-applications-using-parameter-store-and-iam-roles-for-tasks/

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what we do (though mostly using CloudFormation).
I guess it confirms this is the way to go.

Comment: Just to be clear this isn't populating the environment variables automatically, it shows you how to set permissions so a script in your Docker container can grab the values from Parameter Store and set env vars before running the actual program in your Docker container.  It's not a fantastic solution as it requires adding Python and the AWS CLI to your Docker image which at the time of writing is almost 200 MB.  If you're not using Python then you'd probably be better off just grabbing the Parameter Store values in your actual code and not using the AWS CLI.